# Angular Material table paginator with undefined resultsLength

Tags: angular, angular-material, google-cloud-firestore

I am using the Angular Material table with pagination.

However, I do not have finite length of results for the table.

That is due to using firestore that does not give me a count of the results.

What I can do is fetch x amount of results, and when the user presses the next page button another x amount of results are loaded.

However, in order to use that I have to pass a length to the paginator like so:

```
  <mat-paginator [length]="resultsLength" [pageSize]="eventsPerPage"></mat-paginator>
```

The problem is that now I am limited to setting this length to some number eg 100 to get past my problem.

So in short:

- I don't know the number of results. Imagine it like an infinite page table
- The first request to the server lets say returns the first 10 results
- If I assign that resultLength to the paginator then I have no options to go to the next page as the paginator thinks it reached the end?

So the last point above is my problem here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you dynamically load the records, have a rowcount property with results. Assign the rowcount to resultsLength to load the paginator .Use the page event in mat-paginator so that When the user changes the page, automatically this event is called and return the next set of results. Everytime you return the results change the rowcount as per the pageSize.

Refer this link
https://material.angular.io/components/paginator/examples

Comment: That really sounds like a solid solution. I will proceed with the implementation and get back to accepting the answer. Thanks for your time and hey welcome to SO

Comment: pagintor event will emit an object containing the pageIndex, items per page etc. With the use of this params, you can load the relevant data.

Comment: @BearNithi I do know that and actually I subscribe to it's changes .

Comment: Hmm this does not work because I dont know the complete length of the array of results. Imagine it something like "load 10 more" when you don't know how many you have. 
If I set the results length to my first x results that is also my last page. 

I hope it makes sense

Comment: I have updated my question @BearNithi and Sivaramakrishnan

Comment: Can you call a different service to get the number of items?. If you can, then it will be very easy..